# jQuery Mini Colors - Saving the opacity RGBA to the form input

Tags: jquery, color-picker

Im trying to get opacity working in minicolors. I can get the functionality working but I cant save the RGBA to the input field.

Well thats not true, the rgba is sent to the input when i select a color, but as soon as I click off the color wheel, the input clears. How do I save the input?

Here's the code Im using to get the opacity:

```
jQuery('.minicolors').minicolors({
    opacity: true,
    change: function(hex, opacity) {
         text = hex ? hex : 'transparent';
         if( opacity ) text += ', ' + opacity;
         text = jQuery(this).minicolors('rgbaString');
         jQuery(this).val(text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `jQuery(this).minicolors('rgbaString');` returns an `empty string` that replaces the `value

```
jQuery('.minicolors').minicolors({
    opacity: true,
    change: function(hex, opacity) {
         text = hex ? hex : 'transparent';
         if( opacity ) text += ', ' + opacity;
         text = jQuery(this).minicolors('rgbaString');

         if(text.length) jQuery(this).val(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still clears when I click off the wheel. I tried setting text to the string 'opacity' and it still clears off